# How do i create a script that would anchor a object with the click of a button?

Tags: lua, roblox

I am very new to scripting in Roblox studio, and I've made a swinging door for a game.
I made a button that when I click on it, it's SUPPOSED to anchor my swinging door so that it'll be considered locked, so it can't be moved, but I can't write a script that works.

when I've tried making a script, it's always got red or blue lines under the lettering telling me it won't work, or that its wrong, no matter what I try to write in my script it won't work, here's basically what I want my script to do.

ignore the spelling of door, it's supposed to be like that.

```
 local object = workspace.Doorr
if anchored == false then
    Anchored = true
else
    Anchored == true then
    Anchored = false
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Nowhere is the "anchored" property defined! Try using `object.Anchored = true`

And change the if statement to `if object.Anchored == false then`